# taking a random amount of hash pairs and putting it in another ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to take several key value pairs at random from one hash to another. Taking n values from h and putting it into i

```
h = {"a"=>1,"b"=>2,"c"=>3}
n = 2
i = {}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ruby 2.5+, take advantage of the sweet new `Hash#slice` method, which is designed to do exactly this:

```
>> h = {"a"=>1,"b"=>2,"c"=>3}
>> n = 2

>> h.slice(*h.keys.sample(n))
#> {"c"=>3, "a"=>1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get an array of random keys with `keys.sample` then iterate over them to add keys and values from `h` into `i`.

```
h = {"a"=>1,"b"=>2,"c"=>3}
n = 2
i = {}

h.keys.sample(n).each { |k| i[k] = h[k] }
i #=> {"b"=>2, "c"=>3}
```

Or you can just map the sample keys with values from `h` then convert to a hash.

```
h.keys.sample(n).map { |k| [k, h[k]] }.to_h
 #=> {"b"=>2, "a"=>1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
h = {"a"=>1,"b"=>2,"c"=>3}
n = 2
random_keys = h.keys.sample(n)
i = random_keys.each_with_object({}){|m,o| o[m] = h[m]}
p i
```

Results:

```
{"b"=>2, "c"=>3}
```

sample method will take n random keys as an array.
each_with_objece Iterates elements of random_keys with new hash o.

Answer (score 0):

```
h = {"a"=>1,"b"=>2,"c"=>3}
n = 2
g = {pet: 'dog'}

rnd_keys = h.keys.sample(n)
  #=> ["c", "a"|
g.merge(h.select { |k,_| rnd_keys.include?(k) })
  #=> {:pet=>"dog", "a"=>1, "c"=>3}
```

If, as in the example, `g` is empty, simply:

```
h.select { |k,_| rnd_keys.include?(k) }
  # => {"a"=>1, "c"=>3}
```